# jQuery - rotateY depending on element right or left hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotatetransform

Here is a fiddle with my code - https://jsfiddle.net/agon024/o9sa7nyh/5/

```
:hover{
  transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(25deg);
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition: all, 0.5s;
}
```

What I am trying to do is have my div element rotateY 25 degrees or -25 degrees depending on whether of not you are hovering on the left or right side of the image.

As you can see in the fiddle when you hover over it just rotate 25 degrees. How can i do this with jQuery? I found this fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/HeFqh/11/ ) that is similar to what I am looking for (as far as the seamless transitioning but I need it to rotateY.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$( ".billMurray img" ).mousemove(
  function(e) {
 var offset = $(this).offset();
  var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
if(relativeX< $(this).width()/2) {

 $( this ).addClass( "hover-left" );
  $( this ).removeClass( "hover-right" );
   $(this).removeClass('start');
}
else {
 $( this ).addClass( "hover-right" );
  $( this ).removeClass( "hover-left" );
     $(this).removeClass('start');
}



  }
);

$( ".billMurray img" ).mouseleave(function(){
 $( this ).removeClass( "hover-right" );
  $( this ).removeClass( "hover-left" );
  $(this).addClass('start');
});
```

So, idea is: find left and right mouse position ( get center first): https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/get-x-y-mouse-coordinates/ for image, and add and remove appropriate classes. Class 'start' is there because of seamless transition when mouse goes away from image...

DEMO, with slightly modified CSS:
https://jsfiddle.net/o9sa7nyh/6/

Answer (score 0):

At each `hover` event calculate parent element width; calculate beginning and store position of element along `x` axis in an array; check if current `event.clientX` is less than position of current element plus current element position divided by `.length` of elements within parent container. If `true`, the mouse pointer is over left side of element, set `-` sign at `rotate()` function, else the mouse pointer is over right side of element, set `+` sign at `rotate()` function.

```js
var elems = $(".billMurray").hover(function(e) {
  var len = elems.length;
  // parent `.width()` divided by selected element `.length`
  var width = elems.parent().width() / len;
  // calculate beginning position of each element
  var res = $.map(Array(len), function(_, i) {
    return !i ? width / 2 : width * i
  });
  // mouse position
  var x = e.clientX;
  // select array index using element `.index()`
  var index = elems.index(this);
  // check if `x` is less than start of element
  // position plus element position divided by 
  // selected element collection `.length` along x axis
  // if `true` set sign to `-`, else set sign to `+`
  var sign = x < res[index] + (res[index] / len) ? "-" : "+";
  $(this).css("transform", "perspective(800px) rotateY(" + sign + "25deg)")
}, function() {
  $(this).css("transform", "perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg)")
})
```

```css
.philWrap {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.billMurray {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
  transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all, 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all, 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all, 0.5s;
  transition: all, 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="philWrap">
  <div class="billMurray"><img src="http://fillmurray.com/200/300" alt=""></div>
  <div class="billMurray"><img src="http://fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt=""></div>
  <div class="billMurray"><img src="http://fillmurray.com/200/300" alt=""></div>
  <div class="billMurray"><img src="http://fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o9sa7nyh/10/